# Connect local mysql Db with an Remote Mysql DB

Tags: php, mysql, api

i need to synchronize my MYSQL local Db with the Remote Website Db ?

**USING**

MySQL and PHP scripts... please provide me suggestions and steps ?

As soon as posssible...

Thank you!!!!

Comment: replication ? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

Comment: What do you mean by "synchronize"?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are saying about replication about mysql.

```
Replication enables data from one MySQL database server (the master) to be replicated to one or more MySQL database servers (the slaves). Replication is asynchronous - slaves need not be connected permanently to receive updates from the master.
```

This can be done by setting up a slave and master systems ..

You can check more about replication [here](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/01/09/how-does-mysql-replication-really-work/).

Answer (score 0):

The "**synchronisation**" feature you are looking for is called **[replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication.html)**. A replication can be set up between a master and a slave machine. It does not rely on a constant connection, but stores all changes on the master and replays all those changes on the slave once a connection is established.

Please check this [simple tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql)